# Tool support for MOF (Meta Object Facility)

Tags: metamodel

I was looking into OMG's [Business Process Definition MetaModel (BPDM)](http://www.omg.org/spec/BPDM/1.0/) and found the meta-model definition as XMI/CMOF(Complete MOF) file ([download here](http://www.omg.org/spec/BPDM/1.0/20080501/bpmn.cmof)).

Now I was looking for any tools that support reading, editing and displaying the MOF file, but I could not find any. I only found out the Eclipse's ECore is somewhat based on Essential MOF (EMOF), but I could not exploit this relationship.

Do you know any tools, libraries, scripts with MOF support that could handle the mentioned file?

Answer (score 1):

Marius already provided a good solution. 
However, just in case you find it useful, there is a tool by EmPowerTech that can serve the purpose of exploring the UML metamodel. 
http://www.empowertec.de/products/uml-metamodel-viewer

Comment: Unfortunately they embedded the UML metamodel into a DLL. So it is not possible to load a different metamodel.

Answer (score 0):

At least by using google I find several tools for accessing MOF based files:
Programmer friendly:
http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/sam/meta-tools/aMOF2.0forJava/tool.html
Modeling friendly:
http://www.magicdraw.com/newandnoteworthy/magicdraw/16.0#import_export

Comment: downvote - MagicDraw cannot import MOF files. It can only import XMI-serialized MOF